# The system cannot execute the specified program when using pip

Tags: python, pip

I tried to download colorama, but when I write `pip install colorama`, there is an error:

```
The system cannot execute the specified program.
```

Here is the command input and the output:

```
C:\Users\ADMIN>pip install colorama
The system cannot execute the specified program.
```

Comment: Is pip installed on your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Verify that python is installed and working: `python -V` (prints current python version to console)
2. Ensure that latest pip version is installed: `python -m ensurepip --upgrade`
3. Verify pip is working: `pip -V` (prints current pip version to console)
4. Install package: `pip install colorama`

Comment: your statement on the `-m` flag is incorrect. It has nothing to do with python versions, rather it tells python to execute a module as a script by running it's `__main__.py` file. (or if it is a single file module, by running that single file as "\_\_main__"). What is typically unnecessary is to call `python` itself, because pip often includes a script which is directly executable in the shell as long as it's on the search path (and is installed)

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed pip very recently (*first usage ?*)

Windows detected it as suspicious and ask you to "unblock" it first.